# I'm looking for a way to convert this T-SQL into LINQ. Any ideas?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm looking for a way to convert this T-SQL into LINQ.

Basically, I have a table of questions.  When a person logs in I want to dynamically display each question and then provide the answer from an answer table which is tied together by `questionId` (if they have previously answered the question).

Any ideas?

```
SELECT q.*, a.answer
FROM Questions q LEFT OUTER JOIN Answers a
ON q.questionId = a.questionId and a.personid = @personId
WHERE a.personid = @personId OR a.personid IS NULL
```

Comment: I'm more concerned as to why you're trying to convert sql to linq in the first place to solve a fairly simple problem.  Can you give us more detail as to why you think this is necessary?

Comment: It would be much, much simpler to write around 6 lines of LINQ directly in my code rather than write a store procedure and create a class just for loading the Q&A's for this one instance.  Especially, since the rest of my application utilizes LINQ statements.  I've attempted the following, but no luck.

Comment: var qaas = from q in db.Questions
           join a in db.Answers
           on new { q.questionId, personId } equals new { a.questionId, a.personId } into qas
           from suba in qas.DefaultIfEmpty()
           where suba.personId == personId || suba.personId == null
           select new { q, a = suba };

Comment: The `LEFT OUTER JOIN` Linq kata is one you should practice.

Comment: @user860305: you shouldn't put snippets of code into comments - **really** hard to read. Instead: **update** your original question by editing it to provide more detail and updates!

Comment: how you have your entity classes mapped and whether you're using linq to sql, EF, or NHibernate is also important.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer - when the system allows you to - and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you marc_s & ChrisF for your comments as these are the only valuable pieces of information that I have gotten in the last hour. here's how I resolved my issue. I have no idea if this is the best way to go about accomplishing my objective.

```
FROM q IN db.Questions 
JOIN a IN db.Answers.Where(z=>z.personId == personId) 
ON q.questionId equals a.questionId INTO qas 
FROM suba IN qas.DefaultIfEmpty() 
WHERE suba.personId == personId || suba.personId == null 
SELECT NEW { q, a = suba };
```

Comment: Looks like linq, except the upper case.